# What methods can I call on quote->getAllItems()?

Tags: php, magento

This is proving impossible to find googling, so would appreciate if someone could help me out with this one. I'm relatively new to Magento, so its possible there's official documentation about this even.

When I have the following, which is grabbing the quote object, and then calling getAllItems() on it, where can I see all the methods I can call on getAllItems()?

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();

foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
    $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
}
```

I.e. I have seen getId() etc., but what other methods can I use?

And further, if I wanted to have custom data in the quote object, where would I create the custom get method to access this data?

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Getting class methods

If you just want to know which methods you can call on `$item`, use

```
var_dump(get_class_methods($item));
```

to get a list of class methods.

#### Identifying class file

If you want to know which file contains the class definition of `$item`, first use

```
var_dump(get_class($item));
```

to get the class name (`Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item` in this case).

Then replace all underscores (`_`) by slashes (`/`) and append `.php` to it. This will give you the relative file path of the class file (`Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php` in this case).

Now check the folders

```
app/code/local/
app/code/community/
app/code/core/
lib/
```

in the order given for the relative path. The first match usually is the class file you want.

#### Creating method to access a custom quote attribute

You don't have to. Magento will do this for you.

Like many other Magento models, the quote object is based on `Varien_Object`. The latter provides a `_call()` method, one of PHP's [magic methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php):

```
public function __call($method, $args)
{
    switch (substr($method, 0, 3)) {
        case 'get' :
            //Varien_Profiler::start('GETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
            $data = $this->getData($key, isset($args[0]) ? $args[0] : null);
            //Varien_Profiler::stop('GETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            return $data;

        case 'set' :
            //Varien_Profiler::start('SETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
            $result = $this->setData($key, isset($args[0]) ? $args[0] : null);
            //Varien_Profiler::stop('SETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            return $result;

        case 'uns' :
            //Varien_Profiler::start('UNS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
            $result = $this->unsetData($key);
            //Varien_Profiler::stop('UNS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            return $result;

        case 'has' :
            //Varien_Profiler::start('HAS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
            //Varien_Profiler::stop('HAS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            return isset($this->_data[$key]);
    }
    throw new Varien_Exception("Invalid method ".get_class($this)."::".$method."(".print_r($args,1).")");
}
```

Now when you want to have custom data in your quote object, you just call

```
$quote->setMyCustomAttribute(911);
```

Upon such call PHP will check the quote object for a defined method `setMyCustomAttribute()`. If it cannot find such method, it checks whether the object has a  magic `__call()` method and calls this one instead.

In our example, the `set` case of `__call()` will be matched.

What happens now is, that Magento transforms the camel-case string `setMyCustomAttribute` to the underscored key `my_custom_attribute` first. Then it will store the value `911` to a protected property `Varien_Object::_data['my_custom_attribute']`.

To read custom data from the quote object, you can simply call

```
$value = $quote->getMyCustomAttribute();
```

The principle is the same: `getMyCustomAttribute` gets transformed to `my_custom_attribute` and the current value of `Varien_Object::_data['my_custom_attribute']` will be returned.

That's all the magic.

Be aware though, that this is just temporary. If you want to be able to save/load your custom attributes, you need to extend the quote object. But that's another story.

Comment: Jürgen, thank you very much indeed for that - much appreciated. Its exactly what I was looking for, and also explains a lot about how Magento 'works'. Thanks again, and I suppose extending the quote object is the next item on my list!

Answer (score 2):

The type of a quote item is `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item`

You can confirm this by doing: `get_class($item)`

So your investigation will begin here: `app/code/core/mage/sales/model/quote/item.php`

Note: A very useful and much used  method in there is `getProduct()` which will return the product that the quote item represents.  It will give you a model of type `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` and therefore access to the product attributes which can be very useful in a lot of situations.

Also notable is the getQuote() method.

Apart from that just look at the quote item class file and those it extends to discover what is going on and what is available to you.

Ultimately, a quote item extends: `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` and in turn `Varien_Object` (`lib/varien/object.php`)

By looking at `Varien_Object` you will find the `getData()` & `setData()` methods + the magic getters & setters.  These are some of the methods that can be used to get and set attributes on a model (which extends `Varien Object`) - this should answer the second part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that you can use all of the methods in the Sales Order Item Model: http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Sales/Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item.html

Most of the methods are for checking the status of an item, and whether it ships separately from the others, etc., but it also inherits a bunch of methods, as well.

You can also use the old *$item->getData('attribute')* to get the data of specific product attributes.

Comment: Thanks Tony, but I don't think Sales Order Item Model is it - for example, getPrice() is not included there. But maybe http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Product.html is it? Also, thanks for the ->getData('attribute') tip - works great. Now I just have to find the list of all product attributes, and where I would write a custom get method for a custom attribute!

Comment: Oh, you're right. The "get_class_methods()" suggestion above was great.

You could make yourself a nice little module with a helper class if you wanted to add your own custom method to deal with custom attributes: [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table)